# ASP.NET Core 3.1 The type or namespace name DataTablescould not be found. How can I fix this?

Tags: c#, datatables, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I added `Datatables.AspNetCore.Mvc` reference via command line to my `Asp.Net Core 3.1` web application and added `@using Datatables.AspNetCore.Mvc` statement in my `_ViewImports.cshtml` file. When I launched the application I'm getting this error:

```
The type or namespace name DataTablescould not be found. One or more (one or more compilation references may be missing?)
```

Here is my project `.csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DataTables.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.4.2"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="3.1.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySqlConnector" Version="1.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\BSRCore.Database\BSRCore.Database.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\img\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Here is my `_ViewImports.cshtml` file

```
@using BSRCore.Models
@using BSRCore.Statics
@using DataTables.AspNetCore.Mvc
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Here is my `Index.cshtml` file

```
@{
    Layout="~/Views/Layouts/_MainLayout.cshtml";
}
@(Html
.Ext()
.Grid<dynamic>()
    .Name("grd-customers")
    .ServerSide(true)
    .DataSource(ds=> ds.Ajax()
    .Url("/Customer/GetCustomers")
    .Method("GET")))
```

Error page:
[image]

Comment: I suggest you uninstall the dll and reinstall it, or restart the vs tool.

Comment: Are you doing this through Visual Studio? If you are, I would suggest using the NuGet package manager under the Tools menu. If not, I'd recommend navigating to the folder with a command prompt window and then run `dotnet restore` in the folder to pull in the NuGet package. You might also want to check the NuGet package manager settings [using this method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#restore-packages-manually-using-visual-studio). My guess is that you don't have the library on your machine. I could be wrong though. I've not seen this issue before.

Comment: I'm using `Visual Studio Code` and added the package by `dotnet add package DataTables.AspNetCore.Mvc`

Comment: Ok I fixed. I removed the `DataTables.AspNetCore.Mvc` package. Restore the project and reinstall `DataTables.AspNetCore.Mvc` package. Thanks for your helps :)