# jQuery $.notify is not a function error. How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-notify

In my `AspNetCore 3.1` web application, I added required `js` and `css` references to my project for `Bootstrap` notification. But I'm gettin this error when I call the `notify` function.

**Here is my `css` references:**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.18/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-notify/0.2.0/css/bootstrap-notify.min.css" />
</head>
```

**Here is my `js` references**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/5.0.5/jquery.inputmask.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.18/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.4.4/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-notify/0.2.0/js/bootstrap-notify.min.js"></script>
        
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.11/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/scripts.js"></script>
```

Bootstrap notify call:

```
$.notify({
    title: 'Hello World',
    message: 'Hello :)',
    type: 'success'
});
```

Comment: Well, anyway, please can you add a [mcve] to your question as text, along with the full error message. Note that downvotes can be retracted if the question is edited. :-)

Comment: This way is more educational :) Thanks

Comment: Do you have an idea about my other question about asp.net core mvc?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63587055/asp-net-core-3-1-the-type-or-namespace-name-datatablescould-not-be-found-how-ca?noredirect=1#comment112448940_63587055